# How to force wpa_supplicant to connect to AP and skip scanning

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, wpa-supplicant

I have been using wpa_supplicant to connect to an AP on an Android device running ICS. I have defined a few APs within the network block in the `wpa_suplicant.conf` file. The problem is every time the device restarts, it does a fresh scanning which takes up a lot of time. What I would like to do is to force wpa_supplicant to just try re-connecting to one of the APs present within the network block of config file and not undergo a full scan. Am I missing an option somewhere (either command line or in config file) to achieve this without making changes to wpa_supplicant code?

Answer (score 0):

The network info contained in wpa_supplicant.conf is not enough for associating(connecting) to a network. It only provides ssid and its crypto suite. In order to connecting to a network, the device needs more info to learn by scanning them. The scan is a MUST step for connecting.